# Could it be write only permission for the database table (Oracle)?

Tags: database, oracle11g, user-permissions

The process needs to create rows in the table but has no need to read them from that table.

Is it possible to grant "insert only" permission to the role, no read, no update? Usually read is understood as something that always comes with write, but for log and audit entries this is not desired.

Comment: Could you create a "logger" procedure that you grant `execute` access on rather than granting privileges directly on the table?  That would appear to solve the problem you're trying to solve though it wouldn't let the application generate `insert` statements directly.  Alternatively, you could create a view that returns 0 rows and grant `insert` access on that view but that's a much less common approach.

Comment: The procedure seems a good way to go if such permissions are not available directly. While work around, a solution for my problem, so I would upvote